# Using index in LEFT JOIN with OR condition

Tags: mysql, join

Consider following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON
   table2.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
   table3.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key OR -- this is the issue
   table3.column_with_index = table2.column_with_index
```

while I check `EXPLAIN` it shows me index is not in use for `table3` join (however indexes are shown in "possible_keys"). Type: 'ALL'. As per [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types):

> Join type "ALL": A full table scan is done for each combination of rows from the
>   previous tables.

Query is awful slow.

But when I remove one of the conditions so it will be:

```
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
   table3.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key
```

OR

```
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
   table3.column_with_index = table2.column_with_index
```

Mysql is using indexes properly. In `EXPLAIN` result indexes are shown in 'keys' column, type is 'ref'. Queries are blazing fast.

**What to do to make mysql use my indexes while using `OR` in join statement?**

I tried `LEFT JOIN table3 FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY, ind_column)` but no success.

Comment: I think many databases have trouble using indexes with `OR`.

Comment: How much freedom do you have on the projection part of your query?

Comment: I want to load all data in one big query, sorry I can't be more specific. So far what comes to my mind is two table3 joins (table3a,table3b) and `CASE` in `SELECT` part (if table3a primary not null, use table3a fields. if table3b primary not null use table3b fields). Maybe I can go other workarounds but I asked this question because I am curious is there any real good solution for this problem.

Comment: Ok. Also: have you tried using a composite index on `some_primary_key` AND `column_width_index` ?

Comment: @okiharaherbst Just tried that, no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to index an "OR" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829544/mysql-how-to-index-an-or-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you the use of the [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html),

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761574/mysql-use-case-else-value-as-join-parameter) is a similar question you can take and extend to your needs:

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I will go with that. In my case 2xJOIN with CASE statement will be less expensive than UNION

Answer (score 2):

Split your query into two queries, each using a different condition from the `OR`, and then combine them using `UNION`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON
   table2.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
   table3.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON
   table2.some_primary_key = table1.some_primary_key
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
   table3.column_with_index = table2.column_with_index
```

Comment: Agreed but the downside is that the `table2` join operation occurs twice, and `UNION` is expensive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think MySQL is able to optimize `OR` well. I think it can only use one index per table for any particular join, and this would require using a different index for each condition in the `OR`.